# Responsive and fluid thumbnail grid with media queries

Tags: css, grid, media-queries

I came up with this solution for a responsive and fluid thumbnail grid, using media queries:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container>
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/250/250" alt="..." />
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/250/250" alt="..." />
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/250/250" alt="..." />
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/250/250" alt="..." />
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/250/250" alt="..." />
  </div>
  //...

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 251px) { .thumbnail img { width: 50%; } }
@media only screen and (min-width: 501px) { .thumbnail img { width: 33.3333333%; } }
@media only screen and (min-width: 751px) { .thumbnail img { width: 25%; } }
@media only screen and (min-width: 1001px) { .thumbnail img { width: 20% ; } }
@media only screen and (min-width: 1251px) { .thumbnail img { width: 16.6666666%; } }
//...
```

[Sample](http://jsbin.com/qavudo/1/)

Are there any problems with this approach?

I don't feel like using lots of media queries just for that, but it seems like a decent solution for a grid without gutters, considering that it uses basically nothing else than media queries, which are widely supported.

Answer (score 0):

Try using flex layout without writing much media queries.
Look at [css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).
You will have something like:

```
.container {
 display: flex; 
}
.thumbnail {
 flex: 1;
}
.thumbnail > img {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
```